# Count word with a method where it's input parameter is a list of strings representing lines of text

Tags: java, string, dictionary, sorting, collections

I have to write an implementation of String method, where it's input parameter is a list of strings representing lines of text - Count words in a text and return statistics.

1. How can I split the String with spaces, so it will also ignore special characters?
2. How can I sort the map first by it's numerical order of values and then by it's alphabetical order of keys.
   Here are the restrictions/hints I have:
   "The input parameter is a list of strings representing lines of text.

Count how often the word occurs in the text.
If the word "kitten" occurred in a text 23 times then its entry would be "kitten - 23\n". Return statistics as a String containing all the entries.

Omit all words which contain less than 4 letters and appear less less than 10 (the words which are too small or to rare) The entries in the resulting String should be also sorted by their amount and then in alphabetical order if it is needed.
Be sure to make your code handling texts that are not in English.

You may not use streams, lambdas or method references in your code"

`public class Words {

```
public String countWords(List<String> lines) {
    String result = "";
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = mapOfWords(lines);
    for (String key : wordMap.keySet()) {
        if (wordMap.get(key) > 10) {
            result += key + " - " + wordMap.get(key);
            result+= "\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private HashMap<String, Integer> mapOfWords(List<String> lines) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] wordList = line.split("[ ,.-?]");
        for (String word: wordList) {
            if (word.length() >= 4) {
                if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                    map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
                } else {
                    map.put(word, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

}`

I have written code that counts word occurrence frequency and used map to store words as key and it's occurrence frequency as value.
There are restrictions for using streams, lambdas or method references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the sorting:

- Sorting by values

  ```
   Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap = new HashMap<>();
   unsortedMap.put("John", 30);
   unsortedMap.put("Alice", 25);
   unsortedMap.put("Bob", 35);
   unsortedMap.put("Eva", 28);

   // Convert the map entries to a list
   List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(unsortedMap.entrySet());

   // Sort the list based on the values
   Collections.sort(entryList, Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));

   // Create a new LinkedHashMap to preserve the order
   Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entryList) {
       sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
  ```
- by keys
  Just use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`

for splitting String may I suggest using `split(" ")`
example:

````
String[] splittedStr = str.split(" ");
splittedStr[0] => "Hello"
splittedStr[1] => "World"```
````

Comment: I used split, but I want to also split words by special characters. So, for example "what's" should split what and s. Also if there's something in text with double or single quotation marks, mark should be omitted. For example - " "Morning" "  should give back only Morning.

Comment: I was able to take care of sorting and regex. Only issue is, somehow it counts less value for some words than there actually is and I'm not sure why. 
This is the updated code

Comment: That could be because of capitalization of letters. While comparing words use `toUpperCase()` on both so it matches and also `trim()`. If you could please provide and example you ran I would be able to help more.

Comment: No, just replace the first `new HashMap<>()` with `new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` to make the operation case insensitive. Do not abuse `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` to implement case insensitive operations.

Comment: Note that the assignment does not allow method references, so `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)` is forbidden. Thankfully, you can use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` instead.